# Can a Way of Mercy monk heal him/herself?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, healing

The subclass description states "Monks of the Way of Mercy learn to manipulate the life force of others to bring aid to those in need."

But Hands of Healing states "At 3rd level, your mystical touch can mend wounds. As an action, you can spend 1 ki point to touch a creature and restore a number of hit points equal to a roll of your Martial Arts die + your Wisdom modifier." With no specific inclusion or exclusion of yourself.

At first glance I interpret this as you can heal others but not yourself. Anyone have a different take?

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe, as it has been asked before, but about an identically worded feature. Let us know if that doesn't answer your question.